# How can i hold 100! in any variable?

Tags: c#

*I have got stuck in #20 in projecteuler.
It seems that I'm familiar with finding values of factorial but I'm unable to get the value of 100 factorial.
*

Comment: Look at `System.Numerics.BigInteger`.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Next time, please show your work first and tell people what is wrong with it exactly. Read [FAQ] and [ask] coupe of times..

Comment: That's a big number! `93,326,215,443,944,152,681,699,238,856,266,700,490,715,968,264,381,621,468,592,963,895,217,599,993,229,915,608,941,463,976,156,518,286,253,697,920,827,223,758,251,185,210,916,864,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000`

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by Jon Skeet, you should use [BigInteger](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.numerics.biginteger(v=vs.110).aspx).

```
//Add reference of System.Numerics.dll

using System.Numerics;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            BigInteger factorial = 1;
            var factorialOfNumber = 100;
            for (var i = 1; i <= factorialOfNumber; i++)
            {
                factorial *= i;
            }
            Console.WriteLine("Required factorial of {0} is {1}", factorialOfNumber, factorial);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: sorry,i have tried it but it was not working please provide some more clarification